# Qualtrics: How to set Force Reponse Option when importing a txt file

Tags: qualtrics

Hi I need to create a Qualtrics questionnaire with several hundred blocks. I am using creating .txt files to upload to qualtrics instead of creating the questions on qualtrics directly since this will save me significant amount of time.

I could not figure out what to do in order to select "Force Response" for the txt file. Below I am attaching a short format to create a question, with 7 options presented horizontally. Could someone tell me how to set Force Response on the text file by including the command to the block below?

I used the following link for reference (https://www.qualtrics.com/support/survey-platform/survey-module/survey-tools/import-and-export-surveys/). Unfortunately, this does not talk about the Force Response option at all.

```
[[AdvancedFormat]]

[[Block: 1st Block]]

[[Question:MC:SingleAnswer:Horizontal]]

1.This is Some Statement that I want to present. </br> </br>

This is some Question that I want to ask.

[[Choices]]

1 </br> (Agree)
2
3
4
5
6
7 </br> (Disagree)
```

P.S. If you save the above lines in a .txt file and upload to qualtrics, you should be able to see the following:

[image]

Comment: You can't. However, after you import you can select multiple questions and turn on force response for all of them at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to expand on what @T.Gibbons said.

You can select all the questions in a form by selecting first question >> then scroll down to the last question of the form >> press the shift key >> while pressing the shift key select the last question. This will select all the questions between the first and the final question.

Please note that if you have multiple blocks, you need to expand all of them. For reference, I had 20 blocks each with 30 questions in them. I had to expand all and then do the steps mentioned above. Also please note that it takes a little while to turn the option on for all the questions. Please **DO NOT** leave/refresh the page.